# HoloViews/Panel - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'Points'

Tags: overlay, holoviews, datashader, holoviz-panel

I'm trying to create the parameter `px` on the `holoviews.operation.datashader.spread` operation interactively changeable together with an additional overlay.

The diagram with an IntSlider and the function returned by `pn.bind(get_spreaded, px=px_slider) is working as expected when executing with` pn.Column(px_slider, interactive)`.

But with an additional overlay, the line `pn.Column(px_slider, interactive * other)` reports `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'Points'`.

How can I use the `*` operator with the function returned from `pn.bind(...)`?

Or is this the wrong way doing this? Is there a better and easier solution?

I ran the following code in jupyter lab:

```
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
import numpy as np
from holoviews.operation.datashader import rasterize, spread
import colorcet
import pandas as pd

hv.extension('bokeh')
pn.extension()

hv.opts.defaults(
    hv.opts.Path(width=800, height=400),
    hv.opts.Image(width=800, height=400)
)

def random_walk(n, f=200):
    """Random walk in a 2D space, smoothed with a filter of length f"""
    xs = np.convolve(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=n), np.ones(f)/f).cumsum()
    ys = np.convolve(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=n), np.ones(f)/f).cumsum()
    xs += 0.1*np.sin(0.1*np.array(range(n-1+f))) # add wobble on x axis
    xs += np.random.normal(0, 0.005, size=n-1+f) # add measurement noise
    ys += np.random.normal(0, 0.005, size=n-1+f)
    return np.column_stack([xs, ys])

# create a path and plot it
path = hv.Path([random_walk(10000, 30)])
path

# rasterize and show the plot
rasterized = rasterize(path).opts(colorbar=True, cmap=colorcet.fire, cnorm='log')
rasterized

# the callback for getting the spreaded plot
def get_spreaded(px=3, shape='circle'):
    return spread(rasterized, px=px, shape=shape)

# show the plot returned from the callback
get_spreaded()

# create the slider for interactively changing the px value
px_slider = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='Number of pixels to spread on all sides', start=0, end=10, value=3, step=1)

# bind the slider to the callback method
interactive = pn.bind(get_spreaded, px=px_slider)

# show only one plot without any overlay
pn.Column(px_slider, interactive)

# create data for an overlay
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
other = hv.Points(data=df)
other

# show both plots
pn.Column(px_slider, interactive * other)
```

The last line results in the following Error message:

```
# 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[159], line 1
----> 1 pn.Column(px_slider, interactive * other)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'Points'
```

I would expect, that there is some way to wrap the function and makes it possible to use the `*` operator. But I couldn't find a way yet.

Answer (score 0):

Although in this particular case the return value of the function is something that HoloViews could (in principle) overlay with the other plot, HoloViews doesn't know that; the HoloViews `*` operator only knows how to handle HoloViews objects (Elements, HoloMaps, Layouts, and DynamicMaps), not bound Panel functions.

You could use a DynamicMap much like you used `pn.bind`, but here HoloViews operations already understand what to do with Panel widgets, so you can simply supply the widget to the `spread` operation (or any other operation's parameters):

```py
import panel as pn, numpy as np, holoviews as hv, colorcet, pandas as pd
from holoviews.operation.datashader import rasterize, spread

hv.extension('bokeh')
pn.extension()

hv.opts.defaults(
    hv.opts.Path(width=800, height=400),
    hv.opts.Image(width=800, height=400)
)

def random_walk(n, f=200):
    """Random walk in a 2D space, smoothed with a filter of length f"""
    xs = np.convolve(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=n), np.ones(f)/f).cumsum()
    ys = np.convolve(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=n), np.ones(f)/f).cumsum()
    xs += 0.1*np.sin(0.1*np.array(range(n-1+f))) # add wobble on x axis
    xs += np.random.normal(0, 0.005, size=n-1+f) # add measurement noise
    ys += np.random.normal(0, 0.005, size=n-1+f)
    return np.column_stack([xs, ys])

# create plot with interactively controlled spreading
px_slider = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='Number of pixels to spread on all sides', 
                                 start=0, end=10, value=3, step=1)

path = hv.Path([random_walk(10000, 30)])
rasterized = rasterize(path).opts(colorbar=True, cmap=colorcet.fire, cnorm='log')
spreaded= spread(rasterized, px=px_slider, shape='circle')

# create data for an overlay
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
other = hv.Points(data=df)

# show both plots
pn.Column(px_slider, spreaded * other)
```

[image: screenshot]